# How to save an excel file in a particular folder using openpyxl in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPQQk.png)

This is the code I am entering

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime

timestr=datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
sheet["A1"]="Email"
sheet["B1"]="Password"
sheet["C1"]="Phoneno"
workbook.save("C:\Users\HARSHIL\Desktop\Proxlight-Designer-main\Backend Logs\"backend_"+timestr+"data.xlsx"")
```

I am able to save the file randomly in the folder where I saved my python file but i am unable to do so when i want to save it to any other folder.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfvx4.png)

Comment: in error screenshot you have posted, quotes are not applied correctly in path.

Comment: Don't add text as images.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you're using backslash, instead slash to the path. Try something like this:

```
...
workbook.save("C:/Users/HARSHIL/Desktop/Proxlight-Designer-main/Backend Logs/" + timestr + "_data.xlsx")
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlRn9.png still getting an error. Also i want to know will i be able to add date and time in the file name i think it was not considered when you answered the question , thanks for replying tho.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the date and time. Now I included these information. Check if it's ok.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked have been busy sorry for the late reply ^_^